# Template function which accepts a template class

Tags: c++, c++11, itk, template-function, template-classes

I want to write a template function which accepts template class as a input parameter.

```
template<class T>
void Function(T Input)
{

}
```

Something like above. can the class be Template class??
if yes, how do i write it?
i got an error trying to do this. please help me on this.
Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
 template<class T>
    void ReadImage(T InputImage)
    {
        InputImage::Pointer InputImagePointer = InputImage::New();
        typedef itk::ImageFileReader<ImageType> ReaderType;
        ReaderType::Pointer ImageFileReader = ReaderType::New();

        ImageFileReader->SetFileName(FileName);
        ImageFileReader->Update();

    }

        int main()
        {
        std::string FileName = "NameOfTheFile.mhd";
            std::ifstream InputFile(FileName, ios_base::in);
        while (!InputFile.eof())
            {
                string InputData;
                //getline(InputFile, InputData);
                InputFile >> InputData;
                if (InputData == "ElementType")
                {
                    //cout << "Came Here" << endl;
                    InputFile >> InputData;
                    InputFile >> InputData;
                    if (InputData == "MET_UCHAR")
                    {
    typedef unsigned char ImagePixelType;
                    typedef itk::Image<ImagePixelType, 3> InputImageType;
    ReadImage(InputImageType);

    }
    else if(InputData == "MET_USHORT")
    {
    typedef unsigned char ImagePixelType;
                    typedef itk::Image<ImagePixelType, 3> InputImageType;
    ReadImage(InputImageType);
    }
        }
        }
```

I get the following error:
Error   1   error C2275: 'ImageType' : illegal use of this type as an expression

error occurs when i call ReadImage() function inside if else conditions

Comment: what do you mean *"can the class be Template class"*? it can already be a specialization of a class template. so maybe you want to deduce its particular number of arguments?

Comment: Please show the code that failed, and the exact error the compiler gave you, so people can get a better idea of what you're trying to do, and help you fix it.

Comment: @Mat : Updated the code which throws an error

Comment: @Barry And now we are supposed to guess *where* the error occurs?? *sigh*

Comment: @DanielFrey : it occurs when i call the function ReadImage(), inside if else conditions

Comment: What is `ImageType` supposed to be in `ReadImage`? Did you mean `T`? Why are you using the argument `InputImage`(of type `T`) in this form `InputImage::<something>`?

Comment: @Pradhan That's also my guess. OP: If you have an error: Mark the *exact* line in the code where the error occurs with a comment `// error here` or something similar!

Comment: @Barry You'll need to pass an instance of `InputImageType` to the `ReadImage()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a type to a template function as a template argument.

Code like so:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

namespace itk
{
    template<class T, int n>
    class Image
    {
    public:
        typedef Image*  Pointer;

        static Pointer New()
        {
            return new Image;
        }
    };

    template<class T>
    class ImageFileReader
    {
    public:
        typedef ImageFileReader*    Pointer;

        static Pointer New()
        {
            return new ImageFileReader;
        }

        void SetFileName(const std::string& fileName)
        {
        }

        void Update()
        {
        }
    };
}

template<class InputImageType>
void ReadImage(const std::string& fileName)
{
    typename InputImageType::Pointer inputImagePointer = InputImageType::New();
    typedef itk::ImageFileReader<InputImageType>    ReaderType;
    ReaderType::Pointer ImageFileReader = ReaderType::New();

    ImageFileReader->SetFileName(fileName);
    ImageFileReader->Update();
}

int main()
{
    std::string fileName = "NameOfTheFile.mhd";
    std::ifstream inputFile(fileName, ios_base::in);
    while (!inputFile.eof())
    {
        string InputData;
        inputFile >> InputData;
        if (InputData == "ElementType")
        {
            //cout << "Came Here" << endl;
            inputFile >> InputData;
            inputFile >> InputData;
            if (InputData == "MET_UCHAR")
            {
                typedef unsigned char ImagePixelType;
                typedef itk::Image<ImagePixelType, 3> InputImageType;
                ReadImage<InputImageType>(fileName);

            }
            else if (InputData == "MET_USHORT")
            {
                typedef unsigned char ImagePixelType;
                typedef itk::Image<ImagePixelType, 3> InputImageType;
                ReadImage<InputImageType>(fileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```